# Node.js Provider Rest API and angular.js WEB APP

Tags: api, node.js, rest, angularjs

I'm developing an *Rest API* in *Node.js / express* to expose resources (to Backend). And another *web application* that manages Sessions and interacts with the *Rest API* (to Frontend).
API and WEB_APP, is in same domain, with subdomain in both:

> - Backend: api.example.com
> - 2 Frontend: www.example.com

The *web application* is accessed from client with *angular.js*.

The architecture would be for two situations:

> Main_Rest_API <-> WEB_APP <-> Browser_User
>   Main_Rest_API <-> Rest_SDK <-> Client

**My question is:**
This architecture is consistent?
What would be the best way to implement this scheme?

**Update:**

> I have to implement this architecture to provide Restfull via OAuth2 to third-party clients also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really understand your question,

are you sure that you need separate servers for serving the web app and for the API? you'll need to handle cross domain requests this way.

if you don't actually need two servers, it'll be simpler to have one app, where /api/ routes (for example) are the REST API. then your AngularJS app can make AJAX requests to /api/
and / will serve the JavaScript web app.

again, I don't understand your question for the case you do need two separate servers.

Comment: Would be to separate into two projects (Backend and Frontend).
As to crossdomain, would be in the same domain with a subdomain: ex. api.example.com/v1/users

Comment: It can be two separate projects _if you like_. You get to architect your software however you see fit.

Comment: if your web app is at www.example.com and your api is at api.example.com it is a cross domain request.

Comment: Ok, thank you to everyone that responded! I have to implement this architecture to provide Restfull via OAuth2 to third-party clients also